# Session value lost after clicking the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I use a session to save the hashtable. It has different key-value pairs in it and some of the keys refer to 'List' object.

I have different buttons in the repeater control to change the value of the List and then put it back to hashtable. Then use the same session to save that hashtable. But sometimes the change made get lost in the session. Don't know why. I tried on my test server. It can work fine. While on Prod server, I met this problem.

Any suggestions?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCountry" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptCountry_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptCountry_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnCountry" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Country").ToString() %>' CssClass="iButton Disabled" Enabled="false" UseSubmitBehavior="False" CommandName="Select" />
                <asp:Label ID="hdnCountryCode" runat="server" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CountryCode")%>' Visible="false" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void rptCountry_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
if (e.CommandName.Equals("Select"))
        {
            Button btnCountry = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnCountry");
            Label hdnCountryCode = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("hdnCountryCode");

            if (Session["SearchFilter"] != null)
            {
                Hashtable htSearchFilter = (Hashtable)Session["SearchFilter"];
                List<string> countries = (List<string>)htSearchFilter["Country"];
                if (countries != null && countries.Count > 0)
                {
                    bool countriesExists = false;
                    foreach (string country in countries)
                    {
                        if (country.Equals(hdnCountryCode.Text.Trim()))
                        {
                            countriesExists = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!countriesExists)
                    {
                        countries.Add(hdnCountryCode.Text.Trim());
                        btnCountry.CssClass = "iButton Active";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        countries.Remove(hdnCountryCode.Text.Trim());
                        btnCountry.CssClass = "iButton";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    countries.Add(hdnCountryCode.Text.Trim());
                    btnCountry.CssClass = "iButton Active";
                }

                htSearchFilter["Country"] = countries;
                Session["SearchFilter"] = htSearchFilter;
                ProvinceReloadControl(countries);
            }
        }

        InitControl();
}
```

Comment: The add and remove can work properly. Until reset the Session["SearchFilter"] and go back to initcontrol. The values are not stored properly. It happens randomly.

Comment: Is the number of Maximum Worker Processes set to more than one for the Application Pool which the web site is using? If so, then either (a) set it to one or (b) use out-of-application session state.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the reply. Could you tell me where can I set the worker processes?